# COUNTIFS column A or B as range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am struggling hard with the logic here.. COUNTIFS with OR condition for the criteria is fairly simple:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(range,criteria range1,{criteria1,criteria1.1},criteria range2,criteria2))
```

Though.. what if I need to have an OR condition on the range itself?

I have two columns containing week number for "Attempt 1" and "Attempt 2", then one with status, so my formula looks like this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(raw[week1],refToWeekNumberCell,raw[status],{"Success","Try again","Fail","Invalid"}))
```

..so I'm looking to count how many "Invalid" or "Valid" (all the other statuses) I have at any given week. If the status is "Invalid" there will only ever be one attempt. So checking against the column "Week 1" is enough. If I however want to check number of "Valid attempts", I will need to check against both the "Week1" and "Week2" column.. Can this be done somehow? Do I need a helper column, and if so, how do I formulate that one?

Sample data:

Raw table:

| Week1 | Week2 | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 7 | Success |
| 7 | - | Success |
| 7 | - | Invalid |
| 7 | 8 | Success |
| 7 | 8 | Success |
| 8 | 8 | Success |

Table seems to look  good in preview, but not when posted, so:
[image]

Expected result: Count of Week 8 that are not Invalid either in column "Week 1" OR "Week2". Since Invalid always only have anything under "Week 1" then that is easy. But on row 5, the logic fails as I can only use one column as the range..

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output. Which version of excel do you use?

Comment: @Harun24HR done. I'm using O365, v. 2101 for Enterprise. Hmm.. The table breaks when posted.. but looks OK in the preview..

Comment: So would the count here be 4 or 3 for week 8?

Comment: @JvdV  3 would  be the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't get much more complicated than two columns, you could use:

```
=SUM(IF((A2:A7=8)+(B2:B7=8)>=1,1,0)*(C2:C7<>"Invalid"))
```

The "+" is typically used to act as some sort of "Or" validation inside such boolean-structures. However, if you have more columns, the [`MMULT()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66437631/9758194) variant is much easier to maintain.

```
=SUM(--(MMULT((A2:B7=8)*(C2:C7<>"Invalid"),{1,1})>0))
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch (:

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `Excel365` then try-

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(C2:C7,MMULT((A2:B7=8)*(C2:C7<>"Invalid"),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A2:B2)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Was just writing an `MMULT()` answer. This was my attempt: `=SUM(--(MMULT((A2:B7=8)*(C2:C7<>"Invalid"),{1,1})>0))`

Comment: Swap the comma in `{1,1}` for a semi-colon (I think that is for non-english versions though).

Comment: @Harun24HR This seems to work, but whenever all week rows are empty, I end up with a 1 returned.. I got the one JvdV suggested in this subthread to work though

Comment: @JvdV can you post this as a solution so I can mark this as solved?